# Trying to pass some output of lsof -Pi to geoiplookup

Tags: bash, lsof

Looking for a way to pass the second column of output to geoiplookup, ideally on the same line, but not necessarily. This is the best I can muster. It's usable, but the geoiplookup results are unfortunately below the list of connections. I wanted more integrated results. If anyone can suggest improvements, they would be welcome.

```
ns () {
  echo ""
  while sleep 1; do
    lsof -Pi |
    grep ESTABLISHED |
    sed "s/[^:]*$//g" |
    sed "s/^[^:]*//g" |
    sed "s/://g" |
    sed "s/->/\t/g" |
    grep -v localdomain$ |
    tee >(for x in `grep -o "\S*$"`; do geoiplookup $x | sed "s/GeoIP.*: /\t/g"; done)
  done
}
```

The results currently look something like this:

```
<Port>    <URL or IP if no reverse available #1>
<Port>    <URL or IP if no reverse available #2>
    <geoiplookup trimmed result #1>
    <geoiplookup trimmed result #2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of improvements, it'd depend on what data from `lsof -Pi` you're interested in.

Here's a "one liner" (not so much..) that prints command, PID, user, node, IP, port & geoip:

```
echo -e "COMMAND\tPID\tUSER\tNODE\tIP\tPORT\tGEO"; IFS=$'\n'; for line in $(lsof -Pi | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -E '*(([0-9]{1,3})\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}){1})*'); do cmdpidusr=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'); node=$(echo $line | awk '{print $8}'); ipadd=$(echo $line | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 1); port=$(echo $line | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 2); geoip=$(geoiplookup $ipadd | cut -d : -f 2); echo -e "$cmdpidusr\t$node\t$ipadd\t$port\t$geoip"; done  | column -t; unset IFS
```

e.g. output:

```
┌─[root@Fedora]─[~]─[10:22 am]
└─[$]› echo -e "COMMAND\tPID\tUSER\tNODE\tIP\tPORT\tGEO"; IFS=$'\n'; for line in $(lsof -Pi | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -E '*(([0-9]{1,3})\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}){1})*'); do cmdpidusr=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'); node=$(echo $line | awk '{print $8}'); ipadd=$(echo $line | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 1); port=$(echo $line | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 2); geoip=$(geoiplookup $ipadd | cut -d : -f 2); echo -e "$cmdpidusr\t$node\t$ipadd\t$port\t$geoip"; done  | column -t; unset IFS

COMMAND   PID     USER    NODE    IP        PORT    GEO
synergys  16444   user1   TCP     172.1.1.1 59116   IP   Address  not  found
ssh       21557   root    TCP     1.2.3.4   2291    GB,  United   Kingdom
```

if you wanted it as a function in your `.bashrc` or something, you can make it look a bit nicer:

```
iplookup() {
    echo -e "COMMAND\tPID\tUSER\tNODE\tIP\tPORT\tGEO"
    IFS=$'\n'     # set field separator to new line
    for line in $(lsof -Pi | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -E '*(([0-9]{1,3})\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}){1})*'); do     # this is just a regex grep to pull lines with valid IPv4 addresses only
        cmdpidusr=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}')
        node=$(echo $line | awk '{print $8}')
        ipadd=$(echo $line | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 1)
        port=$(echo $line | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 2)
        geoip=$(geoiplookup $ipadd | cut -d : -f 2)
        echo -e "$cmdpidusr\t$node\t$ipadd\t$port\t$geoip"
    done | column -t # organise the columns
    unset IFS # set field separator to default
}
```

note that this wouldn't work for IPv6 lookups, because you'd need to use `geoiplookup6` for that. You could add a conditional that checks the IP type then runs `geoiplookup/6` depending on the output. **e.g**:

```
...
type=$(echo $line | awk '{print $5}')
if [ "$type" = "IPv4" ]; then
    geoip=$(geoiplookup $ipadd | cut -d : -f 2)
else
    geoip=$(geoiplookup6 $ipadd | cut -d : -f 2)
fi
...
```

but to use that with the above code, you'd need to either remove the IPv4 regex, or add to it to include IPv6

Comment: Brilliant! You gave me ample ammo to make this exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your time on this! I voted your answer up but don't have enough rep points for it to matter publicly (as yet).

Comment: Actually the geoiplookup on my server will try both IPv4 and v6 automatically. I don't have to invoke the *6 command.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help! Duly noted regarding geoiplookup6, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ultimately ended up with, thanks in large part to RobotJohnny.

```
ns () {
 echo ""
 while sleep 1; do
  IFS=$'\n'
  for line in $(lsof -Pi |
   grep ESTABLISHED |
   grep -ve "localdomain:[0-9]* .EST" \
    -e "search.msn.com:[0-9]* .EST" \
    -e "spider.yandex.com:[0-9]* .EST" \
    -e "google.com:[0-9]* .EST"); do
   cmdpidusr=$(echo $line | awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $2, $3}')
   node=$(echo $line | awk '{print $8}')
   ipadd=$(echo $line | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 1)
   port=$(echo $line | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d ">" -f 1 | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d "-" -f 1)
   geoip=$(geoiplookup $ipadd | sed "s/GeoIP.*: \S* //g")
   echo -e "$cmdpidusr\t$node\t$port\t$ipadd\t$geoip" | sed "s/\s*resolve hostname.*//g" | grep -v root
  done | column -t -s $'\t' | sed "s/  \s*/  /g"
  unset IFS
 done
}
```